# Looking for Java library to create a block diagram

Tags: java, diagram

I'm looking for a Java library to create block diagrams, which might look as in the picture:

[image]

So far I couldn't find a satisfying solution. I would be thankful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [Java API for GraphViz](http://www.loria.fr/~szathmar/off/projects/java/GraphVizAPI/index.php). [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is capable of **much** more than just those block diagrams though, so there might be a learning curve.

Comment: I used GraphViz with exactly this API. But it's new to me, that you can create such kind of block diagrams I need. Is there a way I missed so far?

Comment: @user1317071 Sorry, I guess answering SO before my morning coffee was not the brightest idea, I could've sworn I saw arrows there... You're obviously right, GraphViz is not really meant for this kind of stuff, although since there's apparently some hierarchy, you might pull it off... **EDIT**: Taking a closer look, I see it's a tree of sorts. So yeah, GraphViz should be able to pull this off, it's all about the formatting then.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [jGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) yet?  It's open source under the BSD license.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I didn't try unsing it yet, because it seemed a bit to complex for my needs. I only want to create the picture of the diagram, which later will be used in a documentation. I also found the Swing GridBagLayout - maybe I can use that to get my diagram.